# Get the particular value from JSON

Tags: jquery, json

I am using this

```
afterEachUpload: function(data){
var xyz = $.parseJSON(data);
console.log(xyz); gives below thing.
}
```

This is my JSON output

```
Object {upl: Object}
upl: Object
file_name: "testt.jpg"
```

I need to get file name. What I tried is  `xyz.upl[0] and xyz[0].upl` both gave me a error saying undefined.

Comment: That JSON output is not valid JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it would be `xyz.upl.file_name`? There's no array involved from what I see, so [0] wouldn't apply.

It's a bit hard to tell but from the example, I'm assuming the jquery response is essentially:

```
xyz = {
    upl: {
       field_name: "val"
    }
}
```

Here's an example of two different JSON objects - one matching what I think your example intended and one matching your request in the comments:

```
var json_without_array = { upl: { fieldname: "it works" } };

var json_with_array = { upl: [
    { fieldname: "it works #1" },
    { fieldname: "it works #2" },
    { fieldname: "it works #3" } 
]}

document.write( json_without_array.upl.fieldname + "<br>" );

for( i in json_with_array.upl ){
   document.write( json_with_array.upl[i].fieldname + "<br>" ); 
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Z4dgy/

Comment: :If there is an array, How do I get all file_name ?

Comment: Iterate the array. Something like `for( i = 0; i < xyz.length; i++){ xyz[i].field_name }` or `for( i in xyz ){ xyz[i].field_name }`.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a working example. It just all depends on where the array is in your object.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your output, I believe you simply need to look reference `xyz.upl.file_name`.

Here's an example that mimics your original console.log: http://jsfiddle.net/VVSvv/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var json = '{"upl" : {"file_name": "test.jpg"}}';
    var xyz = $.parseJSON(json);
    console.log(xyz);
    document.write(xyz.upl.file_name);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Should just be:

```
xyz.file_name
```

Or if you are in to square bracket notation:

```
xyz[file_name] || xyz["file_name"]
```